# HTTP Status 405 - GET is not supported by this URL - Java servlet

Tags: java, xml, http-status-code-405

I think I am having this problem because of a silly mistake but I cannot seem to fix it. So, I have the html file on Netbeans that is meant to accept user details and pass it onto the servlet where the values will be inserted into users2 table

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
           <title>Tennis Club Registration</title>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor='LightSkyBlue'>

           <h2 style='text-align:center'>Member Registration</h2>

           <p style='text-align:center'>Please enter the details of new member:</p>

           <form name='MemberRegistration' action='echousers' method='post'>

           <p style='text-align:center'>First Name: <input type='text' size='20' name='firstname'>
           <p style='text-align:center'>Last Name: <input type='text' size='20' name='lastname'><br>
           <p style='text-align:center'>Telephone Number: <input type='text' size='20' name='tel_no'>
           <p style='text-align:center'>Membership Number: <input type='text' size='20' name='member_no'>
           <p style='text-align:center'>Subscription Type: <input type="radio" name="sub_type" value="life"> Life
           <input type="radio" name="sub_type" value="annual"> Annual

           <p style='text-align:center'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></p>

           </form>

        </body>
        </html>

    I also have web.xml

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>User</servlet-class>
            </servlet>
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/echousers</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
            <session-config>
                <session-timeout>
                    30
                </session-timeout>
            </session-config>
        </web-app>


    And my User.java file looks like this:

        import java.io.* ;
        import java.util.* ;
        import javax.servlet.* ;
        import javax.servlet.http.* ;
        import java.sql.* ; 

        public class User extends HttpServlet
        { 

           public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) 
                                      throws IOException, ServletException
           {       
              response. setContentType( "text/html" ) ;   
              PrintWriter out = response.getWriter() ;


              HttpSession session = request.getSession() ;
              String firstname = request.getParameter( "firstname" ) ;
              String lastname = request.getParameter( "lastname" ) ;
              String tel_no = request.getParameter( "tel_no" ) ;
              String member_no = request.getParameter( "member_no" ) ; 
              String sub_type = request.getParameter( "sub_type" ) ;

              String sub ;

              if ( sub_type.equals("Life") )
              {
                  sub = "L" ;
              }
              else if ( sub_type.equals("Annual") )
              {
                  sub = "A" ;
              }
              else  // should never get to here!!!
              {
                  sub = "X" ;
              }

              try
              {

                 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( 
                         secret login info) ;                                                    
                 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  


                 String strInsert = "INSERT INTO users2 VALUES ( '" + firstname + "', '" + lastname + "', '"
                                            + tel_no + "', '" + member_no + "', '" + sub + "');" ;

                 stmt.executeUpdate( strInsert ) ;

                 String query = "SELECT * FROM users2" ;

                 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query) ;

                 while ( rs.next() )                              
                 { 
                    out.print( rs.getString( "first_name" ) ) ;   
                    out.print( "   " );
                    out.print( rs.getString( "last_name" ) ) ;            
                    out.print( "   " );
                    out.print( rs.getString( "tel_no" ) ) ;   
                    out.print( "   " );
                    out.print( rs.getString( "membership_no" ) ) ;
                    out.print( "   " );
                    out.print( rs.getString( "sub_type" ) ) ;
                    out.print( "<br />") ;
                  }
               }
               catch (SQLException e )
               {
                System.out.println( "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() ) ;  
               }  
          }
        } 


When I insert users on the index page:
Echousers loads very slowly and its blank,
when I refresh the echouser page I get the following error

    HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

    type Status report

    messageHTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

descriptionThe specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
I would also like to add that the same code works on my colleagues computer!!

my files are in the following locations...
webapplication_test > web > index.html
webapplication_test > web > web-inf > web.xml
webapplication_test > src > java > User.java
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a http get request and you haven't defined `doGet` method in your servlet. You should define it something like:

```
 public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException, ServletException
```

Or You should change http method (i.e. Servlet) call from `Get` to `Post`

Comment: thank you ! how can I change the http method call from get to post please ?

Comment: @elmify , you can not modify calls (it is web), but you can redirect them: see my code.

Answer (score 0):

On your form definition you used the Post method instead of the Get. And a get request cant work, because you didnt define a doGet method in the servlet.

Comment: hi, as I used post method in my html, and defined post in servlet I thought the program wouldnt need the get method. Once I define the doGet method in the servlet should I copy and paste same code as I did for the doPost ?

Comment: Your servlet's doPost will be called only when you click the Submit button, but when you request your page just by entering the url, doGet will be called (if it exists)

Comment: the get error occurs, because you refresh and no get method is defined. I think you have some error in your servlet logic. try to debug it step by step

Comment: Oh thank you ! that must be it because, when I enter the details and press submit first I see the servlet page blank, but then I refresh it to get it to work and I think that is when I call the get method as you explained. But I do not know why I get a blank page upon submission. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Check you servlet:

If it accepts POST, you must have doPost:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
// Your code here
}
```

Then if it doesnt accept GET, it perhaps you dont have doGet.

Just put it like that (if you want the same behaviour) to redirect requests:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
        {
        doPost(request,response);
        }
```